# How can I make the form retune an error if the file already exists to prevent the file being edited or overwritten?

Tags: php

How can I make the form retune an error if the file already exists to prevent the file being edited or overwritten?

I am not sure how to edit this code to retune an error if the file already exists to prevent the file being edited or overwritten.

```
 <?php  if( $_POST["potus"] || $_POST["data"] ){        
$name = $_POST['potus'];        
$data = $_POST['data'];         
static $ext = ".php";       

if(file_exists($name)){ //rename exist file with random string          

$n = rand();            

$filename = $name.$n.$ext;      

}

else

{           
$filename = $name.$ext ; // Creates file if it doesn't exist        

}       

file_put_contents($filename , $data); 

}

else

{ 
echo "successfully posted";     
    

   
    
exit();     
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Currently your code will use a renamed target filename to save the data when $name already exists , just change this part so that it will display an error and end the execution by exit();
2. On the other hand, why will your code echo "successfully posted" in the else block ? You should instead tell the user that not all the required data are entered and ask him/her to re-submit them.
3. By the way, you are allowing user to enter something and then save as xxxx.php, it can be a **serious security threat !!!** Please think again whether you want to do it (or not)

For (1) and (2) above , please revise the code to something like:

```
<?php  
if( $_POST["potus"] || $_POST["data"] ){        
   $name = $_POST['potus'];        
   $data = $_POST['data'];         
   static $ext = ".php";       

// Checking the file exists with extn .php
if(file_exists($name.$ext)){          

   echo "<script>alert('Filename already exists ! Cannot proceed !');history.go(-1);</script>";
   exit();

//$n = rand();            
//$filename = $name.$n.$ext;      

} else {           
   $filename = $name.$ext ; // Creates file if it doesn't exist        
}       

   file_put_contents($filename , $data); 

} else { 

//echo "successfully posted";     
   echo "You have not entered all the required data ! Please re-submit the data";

   exit();     
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I enter a file name i.e. abcmouse, I can enter the same file name over and over and it is summited with no error. I know this is a serious security threat but this is on a internal system that is password protected.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that it will not pose any security threats then that can be fine. Then my suggested answer should be able to prevent the same file name be used over and over again. Please further revise if necessary to suit your needs

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used this code to see if this would fix the issue and unfortunately it does not. If a file already exists let’s say abcmouse for example it should give me an error that the form cannot be submitted because of the file abcmouse already exists however it does not. If I enter the file name abcmouse and submit the form instead of giving an error, the form is submitted with no error so this means the form can be submitted as many times overwriting the file over and over.

I’m honestly not sure how I could modify the code in order to achieve my goal.

Comment: This answer perfectly fits to your problem. Just change the line `echo "<script>alert('Filename already exists ! Cannot proceed !');history.go(-1);</script>";` to something that can show in PHP itself like `echo "Filename already exists ! Cannot proceed !";`

Comment: And change this `if(file_exists($name)){` to this `if(file_exists($name.$ext)){` only then it can check the file with `.php` extn exists or not.